# Write concern error: BulkWriteConcernError{code=64, message='waiting for replication timed out', details={ "wtimeout" : true }}

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm seeing this error in a performance testing environment. The wtimeout is set to 7000 and batch size for bulk operation is set to 1000. This environment has lot more data than the others. At that the time of the error, it was processing around 200k documents.

Tried changing the wtimeout to 15000 and the error goes away.

Is there another option to address this error without increasing the timeout?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question?

Comment: So, increasing the timeout seem to fix the write concern error we are seeing. I'm trying to figure out if there is anything that can be done in terms of indexing or otherwise to address the error and not having to increase the timeout. Does that help?